# Work progress report in weekly basis by the users in jira

Tags: jira

How can I view the task done/in progress in weekly basis by the users in jira??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Your question isn't very clear, what do you mean by *done/in progress* ? the status of the issue? and by saying *How can I view* what exactly do you mean? see them from Jira? send a weekly mail?

Anyway, in case that by saying *done/in progress* you mean that the issue is closed/unclosed, and you are looking to the right JQL query, than:

**Closed last week:**

```
project = Development and status = Closed and updated >= "-7d"
```

**Worked on during last week, but not closed:**

```
project = Development and status != Closed and updated >= "-7d"
```

**Opened last week, but not closed:**

```
project = Development and status != Closed and created >= "-7d"
```

and so on.. For more queries option visit [JIRA Advanced Searching](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching). If you have more questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple cli tool [jira-report](https://github.com/veelenga/jira_report), that queries your jira and prints weekly report to console:

```
$ jira-report
Jira site address: https://jira.company.com
Username for 'https://jira.company.com': admin
Password for 'https://jira.company.com':
Connecting to 'https://jira.company.com'. Pls wait...

What was [admin] doing:

Created: 2
  WFM-7180 - Provide static context for log property in BasicHashAnalyzer
  TST-5862 - Unable to install Nginx on HP-UX with Java 6

Resolved: 8
  GSM-364 - Migration of existing scenario
  WFM-5865 - NullPointerException while finding categories
  TST-5864 - Some NGinx installation improvements
  TST-5863 - NGinx minimal dependency
  SDK-7139 - Move common interfaces and classes from into individual jar
  SDK-7138 - Move common interfaces and classes from into individual dll
  TST-7111 - Event.getDonotNotify doesn't indicate about agent's state
  TST-6985 - TST classes should have static Log fields

Reopened: 0

Closed: 5
  TST-6943 - Remove redundant org.apache.log4j dependency from common part
  TST-5862 - Unable to install NGinx on HP-UX with Java 6
  TST-5857 - Put back support for Jdk 1.6
  TST-5840 - NGinx fails to handle interaction initiated
  GSM-364 -  Migration of existing units
```

Enjoy it!